# Webscraper c# . perhaps a more precise webscraper than this

Tags: c#

I am trying to scrape http://gameinfo.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/ but i can't find where the images are of those champions in my webscraping. The problem is that it doesnt scrape every single thing... My script is ...

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Net;

namespace WebScraping 
{ 
   class Program
   { 
      static void Main(string[] args) { 
      WebScraping wb = new WebScraping(); 
      wb.Scraping(); 
   }
   class WebScraping
   {
      public void Scraping()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Type in the webpage you want to scrape : \n");
          string WebPage = Console.ReadLine();
          WebClient webc = new WebClient();
          string url = webc.DownloadString(WebPage);`

          Console.WriteLine(url += "\n \t Done");
          Console.ReadLine();
      }
    }
  }
```

The thing I'm trying to find is the `<a href="amumu"/></a>`

Comment: I would recommend looking at the htmlagilitypack package. http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex.
It's very easy to work with and I have used it before. It's an easy install through nuget. It will make the solution a lot easier to code.

Comment: I have tried working with htmlagilitypack but I didn't succeed. Do you have a way that might work ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: the data is not in the original HTML. Instead, the Champions Grid is populated via javascript. This actually works in your favor; it means you'll probably be able to a get your hero information in json format, which is much easier to parse. The only trick is finding where that javascript is loaded.

In order to do that, load the page in your browser and use the developer tools. I'll use Google Chrome as an example. Hit `F12` to open the developer tools, and then go to the `Network` tab. Now hit `Shift+F5` to reload the page the record the requests. With this done, you can look through every individual item that was downloaded to render this page. I saw a full 238 requests (that's a lot!), but if you scan through the list for json items you'll eventually see a `champions.json` file. Right click on that, and you can get this url:

> http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json

Look at the data in that file, and you'll find this:

```
"Amumu":
{
   "version":"6.24.1",
    "id":"Amumu",
    "key":"32",
    "name":"Amumu",
    "title":"the Sad Mummy",
    "blurb":"''Solitude can be lonelier than death.''<br><br>A lonely and melancholy soul from ancient Shurima, Amumu roams the world in search of a friend. Cursed by an ancient spell, he is doomed to remain alone forever, as his touch is death and his affection ...",
    "info":
    {
        "attack":2,
        "defense":6,
        "magic":8,
        "difficulty":3
    },
    "image":
    {
        "full":"Amumu.png",
        "sprite":"champion0.png",
        "group":"champion",
        "x":192,
        "y":0,
        "w":48,
        "h":48
    },
    "tags":["Tank","Mage"],
    "partype":"MP",
    "stats":
    {
        "hp":613.12,
        "hpperlevel":84.0,
        "mp":287.2,
        "mpperlevel":40.0,
        "movespeed":335.0,
        "armor":23.544,
        "armorperlevel":3.8,
        "spellblock":32.1,
        "spellblockperlevel":1.25,
        "attackrange":125.0,
        "hpregen":8.875,
        "hpregenperlevel":0.85,
        "mpregen":7.38,
        "mpregenperlevel":0.525,
        "crit":0.0,
        "critperlevel":0.0,
        "attackdamage":53.384,
        "attackdamageperlevel":3.8,
        "attackspeedoffset":-0.02,
        "attackspeedperlevel":2.18
    }
}
```

Use NuGet to pull in a JSON parser and you can quickly get structured data from this.

Comment: Thank you Joel ! This really helped me , and JSON is a much better way to go >D

Comment: One more thing ... How did you categorize so nicely

Comment: Just Google for a json prettifier

Answer (score 0):

Regex helped me match the information that i needed

```
 MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, "\"id\":\"(.+?)\",\"", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```